# run time error: torch.cat(): expected a non-empty list of Tensors

Tags: python, pytorch, classification, bert-language-model

this is my code, I got an error and I don't know how to solve it:

```
token_id = []
attention_masks = []

def preprocessing(input_text, tokenizer):
  '''
  Returns <class transformers.tokenization_utils_base.BatchEncoding> with the following fields:
    - input_ids: list of token ids
    - token_type_ids: list of token type ids
    - attention_mask: list of indices (0,1) specifying which tokens should considered by the model (return_attention_mask = True).
  '''
  return tokenizer.encode_plus(
                        input_text,
                        add_special_tokens = True,
                        max_length = 32,
                        pad_to_max_length = True,
                        return_attention_mask = True,
                        return_tensors = 'pt'
                   )


for sample in text:
  encoding_dict = preprocessing(sample, tokenizer)
  token_id.append(encoding_dict['input_ids']) 
  attention_masks.append(encoding_dict['attention_mask'])


token_id = torch.cat(token_id, dim = 0)
attention_masks = torch.cat(attention_masks, dim = 0)
labels = torch.tensor(labels)
```

[image]
this error appear after I run the code and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: it seems like your `text` variable is empty, and consequently, `token_id` is an empty list.